# Compile FastBoot (used for android user space flashing) on Windows

Tags: c++, c, fastboot

I have compiled FastBoot on Linux platform. But I am stucked while compile it on windows.I am using WinDDK for compilation of FastBoot on windows.In WinDDK, It is giving errors like missing "unistd.h","sys/time.h","zipfile/zipfile.h".

Are there any replacement files for above said in windows?.Please suggest if any suitable method to port the code from linux to Windows environment.

Comment: Could you please post the Linux binary for fastboot? It used to be online here: http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Fastboot#Fastboot_Binary , but no longer.

Answer (score 0):

Header file `unistd.h` is available [only on POSIX systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistd.h). Fastboot on Windows [can be compiled using Cygwin](http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/4990ffe551844860?pli=1&fwc=1).

Comment: May I know compilation steps for Fastboot in cygwin?. As I have code and make file available with me. your help really matters for me