# Compile Fastboot on windows

Tags: android, fastboot

Specify me the steps to compile fastboot under cygwin to generate fastboot.exe for windows

Comment: You really should improve your wording. Your question sounds a bit harsh to me...

Comment: A few hours ago you asked the exact same question, which received an answer. Do not repeat your own questions, it will only make you look bad and people may stop answering. It's ok to add follow-up questions, but then reference them and explain the difference. The duplicate q.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243244/compile-fastboot-used-for-android-user-space-flashing-on-windows (the current one should be closed or expanded/revised/unharshed).

Comment: Sorry Frank for asking similar question again.
I have asked it because i didn't get the proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

[FastBoot](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Fastboot) is a utitlity to be used with Android. It simply won't work for Windows, because the file systems, the partitions, the protection methods, the drivers etc are all different. Recompiling such low-level tools requires rewriting them.

In the event that all you want is creating boot splash screens, there's [a utility for FastBoot splash screens](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Creating_Splashboot_Images) that helps you create these on Windows. But that's something else than running FastBoot on Windows.